# How to multiply connection ports in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So, I'm extremely new to UNIX, and we've been given a task in Uni.

One of the things we're supposed to do is to get a list of all connection ports and then multiply them, then get all of the connection adresses and convert them to numbers. I think I've figured out how all ports by using the netstat command, but I'm drawing a blank with the rest of the task.

```
# netstat -o state established '( sport = :http or sport = :https )'
```

This is the only command I have for now.

Does anyone know how to do the rest of the task? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to specify what is your desired output, preferably by giving an example. Also, you need to show your own attempt, i.e. the script you have written so far, and at which point you are stuck.

Comment: I would suggest utilising ss which has superseded netstat, especially as this is an assignment.